# How to not store the completion suggester in the index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I want to have a field `tags` as `completion`, and I do not want this field to participate in the scoring, so I am trying to apply the mapping

```
"tags": {
    "type": "completion",
    "index": false
}
```

And I am getting an error

```
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Mapping definition for [tags] has unsupported parameters:  [index : false]]]
```

How should be the mapping?

Comment: What makes you think that the `tags` field participates in scoring? The `completion` type stores the data in a different way in a finite state transducer (FST) data structure and not in the inverted index.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I thought it is stored in the index. Do you have a link in documentation where i can find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `completion` type stores the data in a different way in a finite state transducer (FST) data structure and not in the inverted index.

You can find more information about the completion suggester here:

- [Official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester)
- [Older article but explains the FST concept](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me)

Answer (score 0):

mapper_parsing_exception
says that it is not able to parse

suppose if you are writing in python
false --> False

data = "tags": {
"type": "completion",
"index": False
}

send this in request as json
json.loads(data)

Comment: I send the payload using `curl`

Comment: you are having properties under type_name ?